Is there something like a "Kuratowski operator" for sigma-algebras?
stackexchange,
I'm learning measure theory right now, and sigma-algebras don't seem too dissimilar to topologies to me. For example, a collection consisting of a whole set X and empty set $\emptyset$ is a sigma-algebra and a topology, and the power set of a whole set is both a topology and sigma-algebra.
I'm wondering how deep the comparison between topology and sigma-algebras run. You can define a topology on a set via functions (the Kuratowski operators), can you do something similar with sigma-algebras?

I don't know if you can do it with a set function, but a relation between subsets can be used to define proximity spaces and zero dimensional proximity spaces turns out to be analogous to sigma algebras.

The fundamental difference is that closed sets in a topological space are closed under arbitrary intersections, but nothing similar applies to measurable spaces. There is no smallest measurable set containing a given set.

I cannot find (or remember) any operator similar to the Kuratowski operator on measurable space. I want to note that for arbitrary outer measure $\mu^*: 2^X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ with monotonicity and countable-subadditivity (, and also $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$) can classify complete measure space, but this will not fit to original question perfectly.
But I am writing a solution because I want to share some intuition about Distinction Between Topological and Measurable Spaces. For topological spaces, we generally avoid a topology that is too coarse, while for measurable spaces, we do not want to set σ-algebra too fine.
A topology is designed to capture notions of "closeness" or "continuity" within a space, defined via open sets or neighborhoods. If the topology is too coarse, the collection of open sets is too limited, hindering our ability to discuss continuity, connectivity, or other (abstract) geometric properties.
In measure theory, the main focus is on integration, measure, and measurable functions. σ-algebra serves as a framework for defining which sets are measurable but should not be overly rich. For example, if we can measure any subsets, it leads to paradoxical results like the Banach-Tarski paradox. Obviously, as σ-algebra richer, the variety of measure and measurable functions becomes poorer.

A Moore closure
Let $ X $ be a set. You can verify that the set function
$$
\langle{\dots}\rangle_\sigma\colon \mathscr P\mathscr P(X)\to \mathscr P\mathscr P(X)
$$
that takes a family $ \mathcal F $ of subsets of $ X $ and returns the smallest $ \sigma $-algebra $ \langle\mathcal F\rangle_\sigma $ on $ X $ having the members of $ \mathcal F $ among its measurable sets have the following properties:

$ \langle\mathcal F\rangle_\sigma\subset \langle\mathcal G\rangle_\sigma $ whenever $ \mathcal F\subset \mathcal G $;
$ \left\langle{\langle\mathcal F\rangle_\sigma}\right\rangle_\sigma = \langle\mathcal F\rangle_\sigma $;
$ \mathcal F\subset \langle\mathcal F\rangle_\sigma $.

For example, if $ X $ is a topological space and $ \mathcal T $ is its topolpogy, then the $ \sigma $ algebra $ \langle\mathcal T\rangle_\sigma $ is denoted by $ \mathcal B(X) $ and is called the Borel $\sigma $-algebra of the space $ X $.
An easy-to-generalize limit example: products
Consider the case of products.
In the topological setting you form the product of the spaces $ X $ and $ Y $ by putting the initial topology on the product set $ X\times Y $. I.e., you declare the product topology on $ X\times Y $ is the smallest topology on $ X\times Y $ that makes the projections $ \mathrm{pr}_X\colon X\times Y\to X $ and $ \mathrm{pr}_Y\colon X\times Y\to Y $ continuous. You then have a concrete description of this topology, i.e., you prove that the set of "infinite rectangles" of the form $ U\times Y $ and $ X\times V $ for $ U\subset X $ and $ V\subset Y $ open, is a subbase for the space $ X\times Y $ (this simply mean that the product topology on the set $ X\times Y $ is the smallest topology containing sets of that form).
In the same way, if $ (X,\mathcal M) $ and $ (Y,\mathcal N) $ are measurable spaces, you can repeat (almost) word-for-word the preceding construction and obtain a "product" $ \sigma $-algebra $ \mathcal M\otimes \mathcal N $ on the set-theoretic product $ X\times Y $. You can still show that a generator for the product $ \sigma $-algebra is given by sets of the form $ X\times F $ and $ E\times Y $ for $ E\in \mathcal M $ and $ F\in \mathcal F $.
A subtle difference
As I said before, bot the product topology and the product $ \sigma $-algebra are generated by some peculiar choice of subsets (the "infinte rectangles"). But there are a thing or two to be aware of in the case of (countable) infinite products.
Consider a countable family $ \{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} $ of topological spaces and topologize their product $ X = \prod_{n\in \mathbb N}X_n $. Then it is no longer true that every subset of $ X $ is the union of ("finite") open rectangles of the form $ \prod_nU_n $ for $ U_n\subset X_n $ open. The intuition to gain there is that
$$
U_1\times U_2\times U_3\times\dots = (U_1\times X_2\times X_3)\cap (X_1\times U_2\times X_3)\cap (X_1\times X_2\times U_3)\cap\dots
$$
is a countable infinite intersection (and infinite intersections are not usually open in the topological setting).
But countably infinite intersections of measurable spaces (i.e., elements of some $ \sigma $-algebra) are measubrale. This means that the infinite product $ \sigma $-algebra has for basis of subsets the finite measurable rectangles.
It's clear then why people denote with $ \bigotimes_{n\in \mathbb N}\mathcal M_n $ this object.
Conclusion
In this case most of what is true for topological spaces holds almost literally in the measurable category. Math.SE is a good place to learn how to deal with the initial/final-topology business. I suggest you to give a chance to it, and then translate and prove the theorems people state for topological spaces on this site in the measurable setting. (I also wrote a set of notes on this matters a couple of years ago but unfortunately it's in Italian).
